# Django how can I get this translated markdown to render correctly on a website?

Tags: python, html, django

I've taken text from my models and used markdown python extension to turn it into html... but it renders as html as a string on my site like this:

```
bot:
<p><code>62%</code> Not quite. You got this! Appreciate your efforts</p>
kaik:
<p>ss</p>
```

Rather than showing the html as a string, I'd like it to format it as html.

My views.py currently:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ChatStream
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
import random
import markdown
from django.template import RequestContext

def send(request):
    message = request.POST.get('userMessage', False)
    ip = visitor_ip_address(request)
    response = routes(message, 'website_' + str(ip))
    chatItem = ChatStream(ss= markdown.markdown(response), user= markdown.markdown(message), name=ip)
    chatItem.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/chattr/')
```

I'm using markdown to convert the text in my models ChatStream into nicely website formattable text, but rather than formatting as html it just prints the html as a string onto the site.

my chattr.html:

```
{% for chat_stream in chat %}
    <p>
    {% if forloop.last %}
    {% else %}
        <b>bot:</b> <br> {{chat_stream.ss}} <br>
        <b>{{user}}:</b> <br> {{chat_stream.user}} <br>
    {% endif %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

It should look like this in the website:

```
bot:

      62%

Not quite. You got this! Appreciate your efforts

kaik:

ss
```

Answer (score 1):

Django's template engine will *escape* the text, such that if the text contains `a < b`, it will render it as `a &lt; b`. You can disable this escaping with the [**`|safe`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe):

```
{% for chat_stream in chat %}
    <p>
    {% if forloop.last %}
    {% else %}
        <b>bot:</b> <br> {{ chat_stream.ss|safe }} <br>
        <b>{{ user }}:</b> <br> {{ chat_stream.user }} <br>
    {% endif %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```